# Apache Beam create timeseries from event stream

Tags: java, apache-beam, windowing

I am trying to create a timeseries of the count of events that happened over a given time.

The events are encoded as

```
PCollection<KV<String, Long>> events;
```

Where the String is the id of the event source, and long is the timestamp of the event.

What I want out is a `PCollection<Timeseries>` of timeseries that have the form

```
class Timeseries  {
  String id;
  List<TimeseriesWindow> windows;
}

class TimeseriesWindow  {
  long timestamp;
  long count;
}
```

Toy example with a fixed window size (is this the correct term?) of **10 seconds**, and an total timeseries duration of **60 seconds**:

Input:

```
[("one", 1), ("one", 13), ("one", 2), ("one", 43), ("two", 3)]
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    id: "one"
    windows: [
      {
        timestamp: 0,
        count: 2
      },
      {
        timestamp: 10,
        count: 1
      },
      {
        timestamp: 20,
        count: 0
      },
      {
        timestamp: 30,
        count: 0
      },
      {
        timestamp: 40,
        count: 1
      },
      {
        timestamp: 50,
        count: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "two"
    windows: [
      {
        timestamp: 0,
        count: 1
      },
      {
        timestamp: 10,
        count: 0
      },
      {
        timestamp: 20,
        count: 0
      },
      {
        timestamp: 30,
        count: 0
      },
      {
        timestamp: 40,
        count: 0
      },
      {
        timestamp: 50,
        count: 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I hope this makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a [GroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#groupbykey) to transform your input into

```
[
    ("one", [1, 13, 2, 43]),
    ("two", [3]),
]
```

at which point you can apply a DoFn to convert the list of integers into a Timeseries object (e.g. by creating the list of TimeseriesWindow at the appropriate times, and then iterating over the values incrementing the counts.)

You may also look into the [builtin windowing capabilities](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing) to see if that will meet your needs.